# How to run unit tests only in a Hybris project?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a large Hybris project here and to run all the tests with takes much too long (hours, yes, a large consulting company created that crap). My target is to reduce all the spring based integration tests and replace them by real unit tests.

But when running the tests with the Hybris ant build for one extension (`ant alltests -Dtestclasses.extensions=myext`) starts a server with the junit tenant also if there are only non Spring based unit tests in that extension. I also tried to use `ant unittests` but that one does not even executes my tests.

Is there any way to run only the tests annotated with `@UnitTest` without any server start in an ant run?

PS: I have a hybris 5.1 and 5.3 commerce suite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `ant unittests` and not `ant unit tests`:

```
ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions=myext
```

**Note**

Running simple unit tests exclusively is not so easy whenever someone uses somewhere `Registry.getApplicationContext()` in the code under test!

In fact, `Registry.getApplicationContext()` starts a Hybris instance. If that happens to you, you need to eliminate that particular call to `Registry.getApplicationContext()` with a better class design and/or mocks.

Comment: yes, Registry is the point where hybris didn't understand dependency injection

Comment: seems you are right for 5.3, does not work with 5.1 (no tests found)

Answer (score 3):

This is good information. However, in my opinion, even running the unit tests for a single extension is still too much. Unit tests are supposed to be **FAST!** I should be able to run a single unit test method from within my IDE if I choose to. The whole concept of "red-green testing" is lost if I have to wait for a bunch of non-relevant unit tests to run every time I want to test my refactored code.

Because these tests rely on a runtime environment, there are NO unit tests in Hybris. There are only integration tests because they all rely on a running Hybris system to be executed.

Comment: You are completely right! The whole Hybris framework is a complete mess and I never mention it as experience to be sure I never ever have to work with it. It is a real pain, worst I saw in 20 years of software engineering

Answer (score 0):

This is for running a particular test class.

ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions="ext_name" -Dtest=com.erk.b2b.integrations.service.ecom.impl.ServiceImplTest

Answer (score -2):

I would like to give some details how to run unittests from within the IDE.

- Install IntelliJ
- Install Hybris plugun (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525-hybris-integration)
- Import the project
- Run the UnitTest as any normal developer will do it
- Enjoy :)

Comment: The real point is that you just can't run unit tests without initiating at least the junit tenant in hybris which involves starting up the hybris system. In my opinion, this is a gigantic belly flop for SAP. Why can't I simply run my unit tests outside of ANY runtime? Running them from intelliJ with the hybris plugin is just another way of relying on the hybris runtime. What if I need to run my unit tests from my CI/CD pipeline? I have to either run all the tests which take over an hour, or I have to start up a hybris instance for each extension/group of tests. Sorry...this is failure.